# Non-trivial intersections of row spaces in Matlab

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Let $W_p$ and $W_f$ be two subspaces (past and future data in matrix form: rows as basis vectors). Let x be a vector that lies in the intersection of these two subspaces. Then $∃$ two coefficient vectors $a,b$ such that

$x = a^T W_p = b^T W_f$

I want to find a, b and x, avoiding trivial intersections (i.e. vectors $a$ and $b$ such that $a^T W_p=0 =b^T W_f$)

I was thinking of proceeding in this way:

$
a^T W_p-b^T W_f = 0\\
[a^T \ -b^T] W =0 \\ 
$

with $W =\begin{bmatrix}W_p\\W_f\end{bmatrix}$. Is it possible to compute $a$ and $b$ based on that? maybe with QR factorization of $W$ to find the null space?

Answer (score 1):

Taking the transpose on both sides, your equation reads
$$
W^T \pmatrix{a\\ -b} = 0
$$
With this in mind, the easiest approach is probably to use the [nullspace](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/null.html) function in matlab.  In particular:

```
W = [Wp; Wf];
N = null(W');
```

If all you need is a non-trivial solution, take the first column of $N$ (that is, `N(:,1)`) and split it into the vectors `a` and `-b`.

Comment: This procedure is correct in principle, but it does not give me the correct sequence of $a,b$ and $x$ unfortunately (I have already the sequence of $x$ so to check the results).

Comment: If you already have an $x$, then you're really solving the system
$$
W_p^T a = x\\
W_f^T b = x\\
$$
which is to say 
$$
\pmatrix{W_p^T&0\\0&W_f^T} \pmatrix{a\\b} = \pmatrix{x\\x}
$$

Comment: Yes, I was wondering how to proceed if you don't have an $x$

Comment: If you don't have an $x$, then what makes a pair $a,b$ "correct"?